# As an Israeli with dual EU citizenship, which passport to use to go to Jordan?

Tags: safety, israel, dual-nationality, jordan, israeli-citizens

I have a very distinctive Jewish name and a dual Israeli-EU citizenship. I wonder what is the safest way to go to visit Jordan.

With my Israeli passport, as an Israeli, I would be probably looked upon with suspicion, but my question is whether using my EU passport would be better, considered that given that there is no tourist entry visa to Israel stamped on it they can easily (and correctly) infer that I have also Israeli citizenship.

Comment: Welcome! 'best' is a subjective danger word here, tends to get things closed as opinion-based, so I've rephrased your question (see the [help]) - hope that's ok!

Comment: Jordan and Israel have perfectly normal diplomatic relations.

Comment: I don't think you have any reason to fear using your Israeli passport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with going into Jordan on an Israeli passport. I know (second/third-hand) people who have done so.

Israel and Jordan currently have full diplomatic ties.

Chances are, if you try and hide things, they'll get more suspicious. Several years ago, we traveled US-England-Turkey on American passports, and from Turkey to Israel (also on the American passport), intending to use the Israeli passport only to get in/out of Israel. In Turkey, however, they did ask to see our Israeli passports. So you see, better to be totally upfront and use the same passport in both places (unless you have a good reason not to, such as when entering/leaving the passport's country).